# I can't read the same bytes from NFC cards

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, ndef

I am testing with Mifare-Ultralight nfc card. It is new and not have private key.

[NFC Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc) app and [NXP TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite) app, show me a difference in bytes read respect to my read data. [result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ICAi.png) and [result 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TEFx4WsqeefzkeqAS3Zj3-KXnvzpnGGY/view?usp=sharing). That why I suppose my code is wrong

my code:

```
byte[] key = new byte[]{(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF};

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<64;i+=4){
   if(util.authenticate(i, 0, key)){
      for(int j=i;j<i+4;j++){
         byte[] readData = util.read_block(i);
         if(readData != null){
            result.append(NfcUtil.toHexString(readData));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

All authenticate in blocks return false, even I tried all key in [extended-std.keys](https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool/blob/master/Mifare%20Classic%20Tool/app/src/main/assets/key-files/extended-std.keys)

I tried commenting authenticate method, but then the result of data is different. I think the problem is here.

```
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
```

If I decode that data the info is there, but no in standard Type2 Ndef format. Or at least not equal to NFC tools output.

Is necessary authentication for get right data all time?

I would have to authenticate in all the blocks even if I only have a record on the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping over the blocks is wrong

if you simplify the loop to just print out the blocks index you read

```java
for(int i=0;i<64;i+=4){
  for(int j=i;j<i+4;j++){
     System.out.print(i);
  }
}
```

gives a result of

`00004444888812121212161616162020202024242424282828283232323236363636404040404444444448484848525252525656565660606060`

So you are reading block `0` four times then block `4` four times, etc

Which matches the repeating patterns in your data

**047B**B94E8B700000FBA30000E1103E00277E**047B**

As a read of a mifare ultralight will give you 4 blocks of 4 bytes from the start address of the read command your loop should look like

```java
for(int i=0;i<64;i+=4){
    if(util.authenticate(i, 0, key)){
        byte[] readData = util.read_block(i);
        if(readData != null){
            result.append(NfcUtil.toHexString(readData));
        }
    }
}
```

which means the start of the 4 block read is:-

0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60

(a read of block `0`, returns data of blocks, 0,1,2,3 )

I also note that a mifare Ultralight don't have multiple keys/passwords for different memory areas and once you authenticated once you can access the Tag until it is Halted. I know you are using a proprietary API to access these Tags but you should not need call `util.authenticate` more than once. But calling it multiple times won't have a bad affect.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Reading every 4 blocks I get the right data. My last question: reading block 4 for example I get 0312D1010E5402656E68656C6C6F20773EE4, do you know what mean the last 2 bytes "3EE4"

Comment: The extra 2 bytes are probably something to do with the API using, A mifare ultralight at the low level for each command will also return a 2 bytes CRC value, which is normally removed and used as a checked by the normal Android API's but I guess your proprietary API is returning the 2 byte CRC value as well with each `read` command.

Comment: in Ndef Record with mime type for example "application/jwt" block 4 have "03FF0133" but data length is bigger than "FF" and If I try to convert NdefMessage of that type to bytes they begin with "C20F0000..." and not "0133..."

Comment: In the other answer I gave the Ndef spec, there is more than format of Ndef message, you can split large data in to multiple chunks and or not use the "Short Record" format. As suggested in the other answer use the inbuilt Android NdefMessage class to decode the byte array of block data. Or ask another question.